# Scaling image and Video to fit the ipad screen

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, uiwebview

I need to load in a UIWebView some html strings downloaded from the web. They contains a lot of image and, some of that are to large for the ipad screen. How can I scale them to fit perfectly the screen bounds?
I don't want to scale smaller image to a fixed dimension...

Comment: what does your code currently look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use max width:

```
img {
max-width:100%;
}
```